# JQuery manual -- how to interpret "index" in something like -- .each( function(index, Element) )

Tags: jquery, manual

I'm having trouble interpreting something in the JQuery manual. Sometimes it'll show arguments for a function. But I can't see any indicator that the argument is optional. Yet, I find many examples of such functions in use, without any arguments.

There's clearly something I'm missing. I'd really appreciate it if someone can explain what that is.

For instance, in the JQuery manual, the documentation for the ".each" method states:

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
```

Yet, I've seen examples that look something like:

```
.each( function() {....... } )
```

How come, here, the function doesn't have "index" and "Element" as arguments?

I've seen a similar thing happen with the "Event" keyword. In the manual, I see things that look like function(Event), and then in use, I see function() in the same context (without an Event argument).

I'm guessing that index, Element and Event are implied arguments, and even if they're not explicitly passed, they are still passed.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, the `index` variable refers to the current key value of the array or hash being iterated. The `Element` refers to the value of the current iteration. Generally, if you don't need to use the index value, the programmer can just use `this` (which is the same as `element` in the context of the function), ie `var left_val = $(this).css('left');`

Comment: Just because some function caller might pass parameters to a function, does not necessarily mean that the function has to make use of them. And naming parameters in the function definition is just sort of a “convenience measure” – a function _can_ access whatever number of parameters it might get passed without this if it wants to. // If you see `.each( function() …` somewhere, then that most likely just means the author of that snippet has no use for the index or the element reference within their callback function, and so does not even give parameter names there.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, your response made sense.